# Public fields vs. properties as they relate to constructors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to C# and scripting in Unity.
Up until now, when making a C# (Non-MB) class, I'd use the following pattern.

```
public class Item
{
    public string itemName;

    public Item(string newItemName)
    {
        itemName = newItemName;
    }
}
```

and in some other script I could use `Item rock = new Item("Rock");` or whatever.

Now, I'm using properties like the following.

```
public class Item
{
    string itemName;

    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return itemName; }
        set { itemName = value; }
    }
}
```

and in some other script I use `Item rock = new Item(); rock.ItemName = "Rock";`

Realistically, I use auto-implemented properties more often than not, and there are many more fields than just the item's name. When I used public fields, it was easy to set all these fields in the constructor. Now, I'm not sure how to, or if it's possible (if I want to keep them private). Therefore, I find myself having to use a default constructor and then settings all the fields with the properties like `rock.ItemWeight = "1 lb" rock.ItemColor = "gray" rock.ItemType = "blunt instrument"...etc. for every item and field each time a new item is created.` Is there a better way?

Comment: You can try this `Item rock = new Item { ItemName = "Rock"}`
Also you normally don't need a Backing Field, you can leave `public string ItemName {get;set;}`

Comment: This depends on many factory and is fairly opinion-based. Thus I´m voting to close this question. In particular setting the members within the constructor or not does not have anything to do with the members being *fields* or *properties*.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Right, maybe the title is misleading but I just wanted to know how to set members within the constructor when those members are private.

Comment: @Nekeniehl Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Then your question boils down to wheather to set members (be it properties or fields) within the constructor or from the outside, which is till opinion-based. In particular it depends on wheather you want to be able to *change* those values and if an `Item` can *exist* without them being set at all.

Comment: You can also define properties using { get; private set; }

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks. My question was how do I set those members from within because I don't want Items to be able to exist without those fields set. I just wasn't sure how to do it since I'm new to all of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Never use public fields!**

Set your brain to use auto-properties like this by default:

```
public string ItemName { get; } // without even the setter!
```

Only add the setter only when it is absolutely necessary for the class to be mutable.

Who says you can't set it in the constructor? Look:

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; }

    public Item(string newItemName)
    {
        ItemName = newItemName;
    }
}
```

You can also use an object initialisation block at the end:

```
public class Item
{
    // setter is needed for this to work.
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

var item = new Item() { ItemName = "" };
```

> I just wanted to know how to set members within the constructor when those members are private.

Constructors are part of the class, so they can set private properties if they have a setter. It's just that outside the class, the properties are invisible.

Comment: Sadly, `public` fields are often an evil necessity in Unity, since properties (both normal and auto) aren't exposed in the Inspector. With normal properties at least one can expose the `private` field with `[SerializeField]`, with autoproperties there's no way to do that, apart from writing code in order to expose them.

Comment: @Galandil Is that so? I tried playing with Unity before but I never got into it... Does the inspector allow you to inspect public fields of a regular C# class? I though only those `MonoBehaviour` subclasses are affected...

Comment: Regularly, only classes inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` have their public fields exposed.
But you can do that with a plain class just by tagging it serializable using `[System.Serializable]`.

Comment: @Sweeper Hey, thanks for the response. I'm curious, why/how are you able to assign ItemName to newItemName in the constructor when the ItemName property only has a get accessor? I played around with this and noticed that it only works if I use the auto-implemented get.

Comment: @embracethefuture yes, that's how readonly properties are designed. You can set it, as long as you are in the constructor.

Comment: @embracethefuture How come it doesn't work if I replace { get; } with an explicitly implemented get block?

Comment: @embracethefuture Then it doesn't _need_ to work does it? You can just set the underlying (private) field.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not sure I follow. Sorry, beginner here. If I want to make it readonly but I type get { return PropName; } instead of just { get; } it doesn't need to work?

Comment: @embracethefuture Yeah, because then you can just directly set the field that you are returning.

Comment: @Sweeper I tried {get {return PropName = "blah";} } and I'm still getting a "cannot assign to read-only" error. What is the syntax for directly setting the field? (Last question I promise)

Comment: @embracethefuture Your ultimate goal is to set a property in the constructor, right? If your property have a backing field called `propName`, then just do `propName = "blah";` directly, instead of setting your property.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you thank you! I just fundamentally lacked some understanding that I'm starting to get now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use autoproperties and constructor like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemName {get;set;}

    public Item()
    {
    }

    public Item(string itemName)
    {
        this.ItemName = itemName;
    }
}
```

Then you can just do the following

```
Item item1 = new Item(value);
```

Or

```
Item item1 = new Item(){ItemName=value};
```

Comment: 'this' keyword is not required. You also need a parameterless constructor for the second usage.

Comment: @SteveHarris thanks for comment, I have added parameterless constructor. I know that `this` is not required but It makes the code more readful and understandable mostly in case if he pass the value in a parameter with same name.

Answer (score 1):

Your question actually boils down to wheather to set the members within the constructor or from the outside. As you´ve written in the comments you don´t wand an `Item` to exist without the members being set. So your decission depends on one single point: do you want to be able to *modify* the values which were set initially?

If you want this, the easiest way is to make those members publicily accessable and give them an initial value:

```
class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; set;} = "InitialValue";
}
```

or before C#6:

```
class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; set;}
    public Item()
    {
        ItemName = "InitialValue";
    }
}
```

If you *don´t* want to modify the members, you can use a `private readonly` backking-field instead:

```
class Item
{
    private readonly string _itemName = "InitialValue";
    public string ItemName { get { return _itemName; } }
}
```

Alternativly you can also create a default-constructor and set the initial value for `ietmName` there:

```
class Item
{
    private readonly string _itemName;
    public string ItemName { get { return _itemName; } }
    public Item()
    {
        _itemName = "InitialValue";
    }
}
```

You could also use a property which is readable from outside the class, but changable only within the class by using a private setter. However this is slightly different than using a private readonly backing-field, as in the latter case only the constructor is able to set the value, whilst in the former case evry code *within* your `Item`-class can change the value of the property.